# Install openmpi and compilation failed with linking mpi_cxx

Tags: openmpi, nvcc

**Hi, All**

I am currently installing the `openmpi-4.1.1` on ubuntu18.04 from the `tar.gz` file.
However, when I use the `nvcc` (CUDA 11.2.2) compiler with `-lmpi_cxx`, it reports that this linking option does not exist.

is there anything wrong when I am building and installing the openmpi?
I use the following commands when building openmpi with CUDA-aware capability.

```
./configure --with-cuda 
make -j8 install
```

I try to remove `-lmpi_cxx` and only keep `-lmpi`, the compiler reports errors like

```
undefined reference to `MPI::Comm::Comm()'
```

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 0):

I just figure this out by myself.
I need to enable the c++ binding of the MPI when building the `openmpi`.
Here are the commands

```
./configure --enable-mpi-cxx --with-cuda
make all install
```